# Drop-shadow not showing up in latest Firefox

Tags: css

I currently have the following set up; however, the drop shadows aren't showing up in Firefox. Can someone point out where I went wrong?

```
.shadow { 
  -moz-filter:drop-shadow(0 3px 1px rgba(51,51,51,1));
  -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0 3px 1px rgba(51,51,51,1));
  filter:drop-shadow(0 3px 1px rgba(51,51,51,1))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS filter is not supported in Firefox yet:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Ffilter#Gecko_notes

Comment: Ok, thank you. Also, is this possible in IE? I know I could google this info, and I did, but couldn't find an exact answer.

Comment: You can see an up to date support state on CSS filters at http://caniuse.com/css-filters